# Can we create and run macros using Outlook addins?

Tags: vba, outlook, automation

Hi I am just trying to create an addin which can create and run macros. And are there ways to enable the developer ribbon automatically using Addins?

What I am basically looking at is to create a clean way to do all of the above without getting the people who might use the macro going through all the developer's procedures.

After searching for long I just found one article regarding distribution of macros, which didn't mention any specific programmatic way of automating all this.
[Article on distributing macros](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=28)!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks guys..

Comment: There's a big difference between creating macros, and installing macros. Its certainly possible to add an addin that contains the macros you want to run (and contains events to do this). If this is what you mean, then you are looking for VSTO (Visual Studio Tools for Office). If you literally mean that you want your program to generate its own code within the target machine though, that is completely different and I am not sure if it is even viable (for security reasons). A VSTO addin would be the best way to go.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot.. And I actually meant creating a macro because I want the script to contain User specific information which they will enter in the macro, depending on which the macro should be created. And just running/installing the macro wouldn't be much of a big deal if we just setup the Rule one time alone. Now I use a batch file to create the script according to their needs and then import it into their Outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I could find, the scripts cannot be easily created and pushed into Outlook using addins (which is more or less like hosting a web app and opening inside Outlook).
The solution that I came up to my problem was 
1) To use a batch file to create the script as .txt file as per the requirement of the user and then renaming the generated .txt file as .bas file at the end of the batch file itself, then importing the bas file from Outlook's VBA editor.
3) The Outlook VBA editor can be opened easily using the shortcut alt + F11.
4) The bas file can be then imported from File options.
5) Create a new Rule with the condition to run the script.